# How do you use Plotly express or graphics objects to animate groups of lines (not points) on a map?

Tags: python, maps, geopandas, plotly-python

As a passion project, I'm working on creating an animated map that charts the history of a specific group of linear infrastructure projects in North America.

These projects have owners/developers and go through phases. Projects begin in the development stage, then progress into construction, and finally into operations. Additionally, at any time the project can fall apart and fail.

As previously mentioned these projects are represented as lines on a map.

Here is sample data from a geopandas dataframe:

```
,projectname,owner,start_dev,start_con,start_cod,start_fail,geometry
0,Texas Noodle,Squidward,2005.0,2010.0,2015.0,,"LINESTRING (-96.17010048422101 30.609632018021074, -94.29757778390804 31.955277817953505, -92.12715374490888 31.99137897723692, -92.12715374490888 34.23677097401347)"
1,Rockie Hug,Spongebob,2007.0,,,2013.0,"LINESTRING (-116.98063685815397 39.14758120357911, -112.34188744146954 36.01183203463652, -106.38386066774642 35.942953095265956, -104.5113379674334 39.41111897268618)"
2,Big Zag,Sandy,2009.0,,,,"LINESTRING (-100.51094856221933 47.40076019809157, -100.08537522123908 41.960019912795076, -97.57449250945577 38.250840193709344, -101.14930857368965 35.389762486211836, -98.76609786420038 33.74277161908697, -101.40465257827779 32.853526045698366)"
```

While troubleshooting, I also created additional fake data in Antarctica to circumvent a Plotly bug/feature related to this issue: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2259

```
3,always_dev,Squidward,2000.0,,,,"LINESTRING (-43.62406605838981 -84.41065520818809, -43.62406605838981 -84.21861499036389)"
4,always_con,Spongebob,,2000.0,,,"LINESTRING (-43.11831819924185 -84.42705076959076, -43.11831819924185 -84.25247944538476)"
5,always_cod,,,,2000.0,,"LINESTRING (-42.275405100661914 -84.4515542624187, -42.443987720377905 -84.26933746417579)"
6,always_fail,Sandy,,,,2000.0,"LINESTRING (-42.02253117108793 -84.36945564024902, -42.02253117108793 -84.27774798403107)"
```

In my closest attempt, I used the following code.

This is admiteddly crude, but I created a separate line for each project for each year (years will correspond to frames).

```
start_year = min(sample_data['start_dev'])
stop_year = 2023
count = int(stop_year - start_year +1)

df = []

for i in range(count):
    current_year = start_year + i
    df_temp = txm.copy()
    df_temp['year'] = current_year
    conditions = [
        (df_temp['start_fail'] <= current_year),
        (df_temp['start_cod'] <= current_year),
        (df_temp['start_con'] <= current_year),
        (df_temp['start_dev'] <= current_year)]
    choices = ['Abandoned', 'Operational', 'Construction','Development']
    df_temp['status'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='')
    df_temp['frame'] = np.where(df_temp['status']!= '',current_year,np.NaN)
    if i == 0:
        df = df_temp.copy()
    else:
        df = pd.concat([df,df_temp],axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)

display(df)
```

Then I organized the data for the figure. Note I add a `None` between individual lines. Plotly recognizes these as breaks between lines.

```
lats = []
lons = []
names = []
animations = []
owners = []
statuses = []

for feature, name, ani, owner, status in zip(df.geometry, df.projectname, df.frame,df.owner, df.status):
    if isinstance(feature, shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString):
        linestrings = [feature]
    elif isinstance(feature, shapely.geometry.multilinestring.MultiLineString):
        linestrings = feature.geoms
    else:
        continue
    for linestring in linestrings:
        x, y = linestring.xy
        lats = np.append(lats, y)
        lons = np.append(lons, x)
        names = np.append(names, [name]*len(y))
        owners = np.append(owners,[owner]*len(y))
        statuses = np.append(statuses,[status]*len(y))
        lats = np.append(lats, None)
        lons = np.append(lons, None)
        names = np.append(names, None)
        owners = np.append(owners, None)
        statuses = np.append(statuses,'N/A')
        ani_temp = [(ani)]*(len(x)+1)
        animations = np.append(animations, ani_temp)
```

Finally, I created the figure:

```
sliders = [dict(
    active=0,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Year: ",
                  'font':{'size':20},
                  'xanchor':'right'
                  },
    pad={"t": 0},
    yanchor='top',
    xanchor='left',
    x=0.1,
    y=0,
)]
fig = px.line_mapbox(data_frame = df,
                     lat=lats, 
                     lon=lons, 
                     hover_name=names,
                     mapbox_style="carto-positron", 
                     zoom=3,
                     center=dict(lat=40.5, lon=-105.08),
                     height=600, 
                     animation_frame=animations,
                    #  color=statuses,
                     )
fig.show()
```

This basically works: [Result 1 - no colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY00O.png).

However, the next step in my roadmap is to colorcode the projects based on development status (in development, in construction, in operation, abandoned).

When I go to add the colors (and uncomment the `color=statuses` line above), this is the undesirable result I get: [Result 2 - colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yN0A.png).

Plotly is connecting all of the lines with the same "status".

This is where I am getting stumped. I don't want those lines with the same status to be connected. I've experimented with shifting to Plotly Graphics Objects (plotly.go), but the code is admittedly harder to write. When it comes to plotly.go I'm stuck setting up the frames.

I've found these examples ([example 1](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Eempet/14825/scattermapbox-animation-forum-question/#/), [example 2](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Ejackluo/2181/us-wind-turbine-dataset-animation-using/?_ga=2.169927968.1007551037.1688309540-49581471.1687045520#/)), but admiteddly I find them challenging to follow, and they don't directly address lines (as opposed to points). The Plotly [Lines on Maps documentation](https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-maps/) doesn't address animation.

Can you please advise how you recommend I proceed? I've been banging my head against this wall for a few days.

Comment: Your question is already of great quality, but some elements are missing to help reproduce your case, particularly your lines of code loading the data (what is `txm`?). Your imports would help too. I'd also suggest to put your images inline.